# Jenkins using external maven libraries

Tags: jenkins

When I add an external library to the dependencies
... mvn compiles/executes fine
... but Jenkins fails.

I used the tutorial code: 
https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/

Summary of what I did.

- made the jar executable the Run class
- added commons-io as a pom dependency
- created a new class called Run.
- printed out the temp directory using FileUtils.getTempDirectoryPath()

What is the best way to make this code work NOT throw exceptions in a Jenkins pipeline?
https://github.com/fodon/step-two-jenkins.git

Answer (score 0):

I chose to copy libraries in the build process

The github repo now doesn't works fine.

Any better ideas?